# ¿Cuál es la traducción de "semantic range" a español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

Estoy cambiando muchos [tags](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags) de inglés a español, pero encontré uno ([semantic-range](/questions/tagged/semantic-range)) que no sé, y Wikipedia no tiene la respuesta.

Google Translate dice

> alcance semántico

Pero no tengo confianza en Google para términos tetánicos así.  ¿Cómo se dice eso en español?

Answer (score 3):

`Semantic Range` se refiere al alcance de una palabra semanticamente.  Eso significa la cantidad de usos en que una palabra puede ser utilizado, con diferentes contextos.

Para explicarlo mejor:
Es una cantidad de 'sinónimos' de una palabra.  No necesariamente sólo sinónimos sino diferentes distintos contextos

A ver a `pasar`.. Tiene muchos alcances semánticos.

- dar
- transmitir
- experimentar
- irse
- moverse
- poder entrar
- terminarse
- tolerar
- desaprovecharse
- cesar

Hay muchísimas palabras más...

En este ejemplo, `pasar(se)` lleva 10.  Su `alcance semántico` es 10... hipotéticamente.

Para contestarte, la traducción es `Alcance semántico`.
[Aquí es mi fuente](http://bit.ly/1yWvXfL)

Comment: Entonces ¿cuál es la traducción?

Comment: Alcance semántico

Answer (score 2):

Paréceme que normalmente las formas usadas en castellano son **gama semántica**, **ámbito semántico** o, como indica Google, **alcance semántico**, y menos frecuentemente **rango semántico** (principalmente pero no exclusivamente en traducciones del inglés).

Según [Google N-Grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gama+sem%C3%A1ntica%2Crango+sem%C3%A1ntico%2C%C3%A1mbito+sem%C3%A1ntico%2Calcance+sem%C3%A1ntico&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgama%20sem%C3%A1ntica%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crango%20sem%C3%A1ntico%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A1mbito%20sem%C3%A1ntico%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calcance%20sem%C3%A1ntico%3B%2Cc0), en los 70, disfrutaban de una frecuencia de uso casi igual.  Hoy en día, es claramente preferido «ámbito semántico», seguido por «alcance semántico» y ese por «gama semántica».

Ten en cuenta que, a «hojear» (si se puede en Internet) los artículos que usan *ámbito semántico* a mi parecer también refieren a las estructuras gramaticales en vez de solo las palabras en sí (es decir, su significado en contextos metafóricos, etc).  Puede que ello anule un poco los resultados de los N-Grams, dependiendo del contexto.  Gama semántica parece ser más el término por sí solo, y alcance semántico de uso entre los dos.  Tendría que leer algunos más profundamente para dar una respuesta más precisa.

Answer (score 0):

No encuentro mucho pero aparentemente "Semantic Range" tiene el mismo significado que Polisemia.